# Migrating data from local SQL Server generated script to Azure web app SQL Server, when it failed executing from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have generated 200 mega data script from local SQL Server, which I generated via Tasks -> Generate Script in SQL Server Management Studio.

When I try to execute it from the SQL Server Management Studio, I get massage that I have not enough memory to run it, which is weird I have 16 gigabytes of ram in my pc.

So my question is simple: how can I update my remote SQL Server with the data script ?

Can I configure SQL Server Management Studio to use more memory or there is better way to execute big script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SQLCMD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms170572.aspx)..

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sqlsqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql -o C:\EmpAdds.txt
```

This [link provides details on why you are seeing the issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/51ef4b81-6677-4e2d-8b80-648633cf699e/sql-server-management-studio-20052008-what-is-the-largest-sql-file-supported-that-i-can-open?forum=sqltools)..

> There is no hard-coded limit on the size of file that SSMS can open or execute, so the question of how large a file SSMS can open is hard to answer concretely. 
>   However, SSMS is a 32-bit application so its maximum address space is 2 GB.  SSMS uses many managed code components that are garbage collected, so its working set is often over 1 GB without loading any files if you've been using any of the UI launched from from Object Explorer.  If SSMS has been running for a while, the free memory for the process tends to become fragmented, so the largest contiguous free address range can be less than 100 MB.  The text editor uses UNICODE (UTF-16) as its internal representation, so a 50 MB ASCII text file can take 100 MB of memory to store.  The text editor allocates a single block of memory to store the document text, so if Windows can't allocate a block as big as the editor needs, the text editor can't even load the document.
>
> When you try to execute a script, SSMS breaks the document up into SQL batches (which is one copy of the text), and then sends the batch to the server to execute (which is a second copy).  The batches are much smaller than the document, so the free address block sizes aren't a problem, but having three copies of the document text in memory may not be possible if the script is large enough.  The result is that after a restart, SSMS can usually load and edit documents that are larger than what it can execute.
>
> After turning off intellisense, I've been able to load documents as large as 200 MB in my test machine just after starting SSMS, but I wasn't able to run them.  That is probably close to the limit of what's possible in a lab environment.  In the real world, with less beefy machines and actually using SSMS to get your job done, the practical limit is probably more like loading and executing a 40 MB script.